# The closed points are a constructible set?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field.
Consider the affine scheme Spec $k[x_1,...,x_m]$.
The set of closed points $k^m$(i.e. the maximal ideals) is a constructible set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That set is not constructible.

Recall that in a noetherian topological space $X$, a set $E$ is constructible if and only if for every irreducible closed subset $Z\subset X$, the intersection $E\cap Z$ either contains a nonempty open of $Z$ or is not dense in $Z$.

Now let $X$ be Spec$(k[x_1,...,x_m])$ and let $E$ be the set of closed points.  We will show that $E$ is dense in $X$ and contains no nonempty open of $X$.  By the above, this will imply that $E$ is not constructible.

To prove $E$ is dense in $X$, it suffices to show that every nonempty open $U\subset X$ intersects $E$.  Well, by Nullstellensatz, for any nonzero $f\in k[x_1,...x_m]$, there must be some closed point $p \in X$ such that $f(p)\neq 0$.  Then $p\in D(f)$.  Since these opens form a basis for the topology, $E$ must be dense in $X$.

Every basis open $D(f)$ contains the generic point of $X$, which is of course not in $E$.  So $E$ does not contain any nonempty open of $X$.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I haven't understood the property written in the second sentence.  I tried to find it in Vakil's note and Hartshorne but I couldn't find it. May I have a reference or proof?

Comment: Sure, it's a fact of point-set topology, and can be found in the Stacks Project as Lemma 5.11.3.

Comment: I understood! Your proof needs the only-if part only, which is easier than the if-part. I appreciate it.